# Why Alarm not fired when I remove app from recent apps?

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-alarms

I can see many apps that can handle more complex situations like *Notifications* and it's work verywell.

**Requirement:**

I'm just trying to set an alarm to fire at specific time

**Problem:**

It's work only if app exist in recent apps, if I removed it from recent apps no alarm fired!

**Questions:**

Why it's not working? - What should I do to make it working?

**My Code Snipp:**

What my alarm firing look like:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyBroadcastReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
    this.getApplicationContext(), PENDING_INTENT_ID, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
assert alarmManager != null;
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
  alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeInMilliseconds, pendingIntent);
} else {
  alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeInMilliseconds, pendingIntent);
}
```

What MyBroadcastReceiver look like:

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private static final String TAG = "MyBroadcastReceiver";
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.i(TAG, "BroadCast Fired!");

}
```

Enable for boot:

```
ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(this, MyBroadcastReceiver.class);
PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName,
        componentEnabledState,
        PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

Manifest:

```
 <receiver
        android:name="MyBroadcastReceiver"
        android:enabled="false">

        <intent-filter>
            <action
                android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: Are you testing on a physical device? If so, which brand/model is it?

Comment: @jmart I've tested on emulator pixel2 and it's worked, BUT not worked on my physical device OPPO A71

Comment: @jmart "EDIT" sry, I tested on Nexus S not pixel 2.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because the manufacturer of your device (Oppo) added a custom setting to kill apps when they are removed from the list of recent apps.

This is NOT standard Android behavior. In normal Android, an app is not killed when removed from the list of recent apps (and that's why it worked correctly on the emulator).

The solution is to locate where this setting resides in your device and change it. In some devices, you may need to pin the app to the list of recent apps too, so it doesn't get removed. But this may change depending on the specific device model.

If you can't find the setting, I recommend to search in Oppo forums or check this page: https://dontkillmyapp.com/

But your code is correct. There's nothing more you can do from the app.

Comment: In fact, there's an open issue about this problem on the google issue tracker, I recommend to star it: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/122098785

Comment: But there in other new apps on GOOGLE-PLAY which is already working!.. any idea?

Comment: Preloaded apps and well-known apps are not blocked. Oppo (and other Chinese manufacturers) only block downloaded apps or less-known apps. They play unfairly and that's the reason why webs like https://dontkillmyapp.com/ exist.